# Regex for a single range or comma separated string of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a text field that I want to only accept a single range of numbers (eg. "1000-3000") OR a comma-separated list of numbers (eg. "1003", "1004", "2000") but not both. Some examples of expected results:

```
1000 (valid)
1000, 2000 (valid)
1000 ,2000 (valid)
1000, 2000, (valid)
,1000, 2000 (invalid)
1000,1000 (valid)
1000-2000, 3000-3500 (invalid).
1000-2000, 3000 (invalid).
1000 - 2000 (valid)
1000-2000 (valid)
,1000 (invalid)
```

This is what I have which doesn't work fully:

```
let input = "1000, 5000-6000"
input.match(/^(([0-9\s](,)?(-)?)*)+$/); // returns a match

input = "1000 - 3 000"  
input.match (/^(([0-9\s](,)?(-)?)*)+$/)// returns a match (space in second num)

let input = "5000-"
input.match(/^(([0-9\s](,)?(-)?)*)+$/); // returns a match
```

My version might fail in other ways I haven't found yet, but those 3 examples of matches shouldn't work. I'm using javascript/react.

Comment: Hmm...do you really want to accept `1000, 2000,` with a trailing comma?

Comment: not really but it's not a deal breaker as much as the others

Comment: Looks like eg [`^\d+(?: *- *\d+|(?: *, *\d+)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/wJiuKb/1) would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern, which matches a number either followed by a hyphen and another number (single range), or by comma and and another number, any number of times (CSV list).

```
^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*,?)$
```

Sample script:

```js
var inputs = ["1000", "1000, 2000", "1000 ,2000", "1000, 2000,", "1000,1000", "1000 - 2000", "1000-2000", ",1000, 2000", "1000-2000, 3000-3500", "1000-2000, 3000", ",1000"];
inputs.forEach(x => console.log(x + " => " + /^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*,?)$/.test(x)));
```

Comment: excellent. If I don't want to accept a trailing comma: ```1000,2000,```  how would this be altered? it's not a big deal but i'd rather not if i can help it.

Comment: Use: `^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)$`

Comment: If I now want to allow the user to type a certain label followed by a colon to indicate the expression to be validated, would it be more complex? So instead of allowing only csv or range, for them to say: "Buildings: [existing pattern]". So it's literally a certain word and colon, and only once, and then applying the pattern you provided which works beautifully. There might also be other labels to allow as well but ```buildings:``` is now what I need. Or would it be easier to strip that label out and validate using the existing pattern? thanks

Comment: @MattoMK Please ask a new question.